# Magento 2 - Something Went Wrong?

Tags: magento2

Every time I goto products and click on any particular product I get the following error

```
jquery.js:9666 GET http://192.168.1.176/wmgr/mui/index/render/key/5c8e239c07b73e71850f0c57868db87dcef095fbe86124cea5f76f9d75745184/?namespace=review_listing&isAjax=true 500 (Internal Server Error)send @ jquery.js:9666ajax @ jquery.js:9211requestData @ insert.js:228(anonymous function) @ insert.js:135(anonymous function) @ async.js:135(anonymous function) @ events.js:85trigger @ events.js:82trigger @ events.js:159addBounded @ bound-nodes.js:42applyBindings @ bound-nodes.js:128(anonymous function) @ wrapper.js:78(anonymous function) @ knockout.js:4862invokeForEachNodeInContinuousRange @ knockout.js:4813activateBindingsOnContinuousNodeArray @ knockout.js:4860executeTemplate @ knockout.js:4908ko.dependentObservable.disposeWhen @ knockout.js:4950evaluateImmediate @ knockout.js:1737evaluatePossiblyAsync @ knockout.js:1677notifySubscribers @ knockout.js:1103observable.valueHasMutated @ knockout.js:1300observable @ knockout.js:1285(anonymous function) @ engine.js:54fire @ jquery.js:3099fireWith @ jquery.js:3211(anonymous function) @ jquery.js:3263fire @ jquery.js:3099fireWith @ jquery.js:3211deferred.(anonymous function) @ jquery.js:3301(anonymous function) @ loader.js:96execCb @ require.js:1650context.execCb @ resolver.js:131check @ require.js:866(anonymous function) @ require.js:1113(anonymous function) @ require.js:132(anonymous function) @ require.js:1156each @ require.js:57emit @ require.js:1155check @ require.js:917enable @ require.js:1143init @ require.js:774(anonymous function) @ require.js:991(anonymous function) @ require.js:132(anonymous function) @ text.js:149xhr.onload @ text.js:112
```

Answer (score 1):

Problem was causing because I've had Magento Review module disable in Advance settings after enabling that everything works fine but not sure why its causing that because I've Yotpo review module I guess I've to get in touch with Yotpo people about this.